# spaCy: Finding the sentences from which tokens extracted with dependency matcher come from

Tags: python, spacy

I have a list of tuples right here that represent dependency patterns extracted with spacy dependency matcher :

```
dep_patterns =[('nsubj_verb', rabbits, jumping),
               ('nsubj_verb', grass, getting),
               ('nsubj_verb', they, come)
              ]
```

Just in case, here is part of text file I'm working with:

```
text_file = "The rabbits are jumping in the garden. The grass is getting shorter and shorter by the day. Every evening, they come to this garden at the same time."
```

I'm trying to get the full sentences from which these patterns were extracted. I know I can use token.sent to find the sentence from which a token comes from but I'm running into problems trying to implement that solution.

I tried this code

```
for pattern in text_for_patterns:
    (pattern_name, subject, verb) = pattern
    for subject, verb in pattern[1:2]:
        sents = (subject.text, verb.text).sent
        comp_sentences.append(sents)
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-5c4560e7ea5d> in <module>
     22 for pattern in text_for_patterns:
     23     (pattern_name, subject, verb) = pattern
---> 24     for subject, verb in pattern[1:2]:
     25         sents = (subject.text, verb.text).sent
     26         comp_sentences.append(sents)

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable spacy.tokens.token.Token object
```

There might be a couple of things I'm missing here, but after spending some time thinking about it and Googling, I'm running of ideas...

Comment: What if you just take the innermost `for` statement out (line 24)? (and obviously fix the indentation on lines 25 and 26).  You've already extracted `subject` and `verb` from the `pattern` tuple so you don't need to iterate further.

Comment: I think this could indedd be a start but when I do that, I get this error : AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sent

Comment: Right, I think `.sent` is an attribute of a single token rather than a tuple: https://spacy.io/api/token#attributes.  So `subject.sent` and `verb.sent` might individually work?

Comment: It does! Although it returns the sentences twice because each subject, verb pair comes from the same sentence, so technically if I want the sentences only once, I'd have to use either subject.sent or verb.sent. Someone reading the code later would maybe ask why the chosen option was selected, but at least it works for now. Thanks for the help!